# Get full dragged file path in Titanium Desktop via javascript

Tags: javascript, file, html, titanium, appcelerator

With the html5 file api, you can drag files onto a webpage and you can access the data from them. In a Titanium Desktop application, is there a way to get the full path of a file dragged? Titanium gives you full filesystem access, so you ought to be able to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/115341/titanium-desktop---drag--drop) it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen that one yet. Having the users drag a file into a specific area isn't quite what I hoped for, but it will work. Thanks!